# will_paginate on array only displays first page of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I need to paginate an array. When I click the other pages, I see the same 25 items as displayed on the first page. The URL is `http://localhost:3000/?page=2` but it's the same 25 items. There are about 100 total.

Here's my controller method:

```
def index
  @items = Array.new
  API.items.all! do |i|
    @items << i
  end
  @paginated_items = @items.paginate(per_page: 25)
end
```

Here is my html file:

```
<%= will_paginate @paginated_items %>

<ul class="items">
  <% @paginated_items.each do |i| %>
    <li>Subject: <%= i.subject %>, ID: <%= i.id %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate @paginated_items %>
```

I also added `require 'will_paginate/array'` to an initializer.

Comment: I am getting it from an external API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missing page: params[:page] in index controller, this is how will_paginate know what page you currently now

```
def index
  @items = Array.new
  API.items.all! do |i|
    @items << i
  end
  @paginated_items = @items.paginate(page:params[:page],per_page:25)
end
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. :)